# how to split the string to check all the constraints in C# console program

Tags: c#, console-application

i want to creat a program in c# in which user will enter a string like 
BC12054321 as argument in a method. 
Here
BC (first two characters from left) will show its Bachelor, It can MC to  represents MCS.
12 (3rd and 4th characters from left) represent enrollment year which cannot be more than 2015 and less than 2012)
04 (5th and 6th characters from left) represents enrolled semester. it can be 02 or 04 now 02 will represent Spring semester and 04 will represent Fall semester
54321 (last 5 characters) represents student unique id.

this is the whole case now I am confuse weather I use array to store that string or simple variable. if I use simple variable then how could I apply these all constraint in a single variable I mean how can I split this string to check all the conditions. can any body help me? I also attached that what I actually want to do please see the gif picture :

[image]

Comment: Use substring to place the items into an array?

Comment: what you suggest after watching the gif image

Comment: Actually, I spoke up faster than I should have. If it were me, I'd store each value in a variable. Sorry about that.

Comment: but there would be a single variable which will take only one string from user as argument of a method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store user input into a variable, then use `Substring` to split each value out to separate variables.

```
string studentInfo = Console.ReadLine();
string studentProgram = studentInfo.Substring(0, 2);
string studentYearOfEnrollment = studentInfo.Substring(2, 2);
string studentSemester = studentInfo.Substring(4, 2);
string studentID = studentInfo.Substring(6, 5);
```

Comment: what are these parameters in substring can you please explain it bit more

Comment: The first int is the index you want to start the string at. The second int is the length of the string.

Comment: oh I got it. let me try it , I hope it will work

Comment: I would also take a look at Scott Hannen's answer. That's a good way to handle the exceptions the user's input may throw.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class that represents whatever the data is that you're retrieving. Your data represents something, so it's better to define that something than to use an array of values.

```
public class Enrollment
{
    public int EnrollmentYear {get;set;}
    public int Semester {get;set;}
    //etc
}
```

Then write an extension class that parses a string and returns an enrollment, perhaps like this:

```
public static class EnrollmentExtensions
{
    public Enrollment ParseEnrollment(this string enrollmentString)
    {
        var enrollment = new Enrollment();
        //Now you can inspect substrings and set the properties
        //on the class before returning it.
        //If the string can't be parsed into an enrollment then
        //you could throw an exception.
    }
}
```

That way all of the logic to convert a string into an `Enrollment` is separate from your main method.

You could do something like this:

```
var input = Console.Readline();
Enrollment enrollment = null;
try
{
    enrollment = input.ParseEnrollment();
}
catch(Exception ex)//Whatever exception type you throw
{
    //Error message or repeat showing the correct format.
}
```

Comment: Heck, if he combines our answers he'll have a working application lmao.

Comment: why don't you combine it. I am confuse I am new student of C# and programming as well

Comment: Because if you're a student and I did it for you, what would you learn?

Comment: I will read and learn it for the first time and then I will remember it for future.

Comment: Whoah buddy, that's not a good mindset to have for any development language. Your best bet is to look at the above answer and my answer very carefully. Scott's answer tells you where to put part of my answer. Then, when you've figured it out. Look up the different parts of our answers. Your key words here being Substring, Class, Extension Class, Exception. That'll get you started.

Comment: ok I try it. thanks for the guidance. can u suggest me good tutor of C#

Comment: learncs.org is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I would use only 1 variable

For validation you could use a simple regex like this

^(BA|MA)(12|13|14|15)(02|04)\d{5}$

Comment: I don't know what is regex. can you explain.

Comment: You can learn about C# regex here [C# regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) and here [C# string regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: also you can play with .net regex [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester)